# Spring Batch UNKNOWN status during job execution

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a batch flow job which does some heavy operations with multiple intermediate steps.

After the job completion, it returns the `COMPLETED` or `FAILED` statuses(that's totally fine) but during the execution, it returns `UNKNOWN` status.

Is it possible to control the job statuses during its execution and returns something more meaningful instead of `UNKNOWN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UNKNOWN` status is only returned on a failed rollback.  When a rollback fails, we don't know what the underlying state of the system is which is why `UNKNOWN` is returned.  In this scenario, human intervention is typically required.

Comment: Thanks, my issue was that I used ExitStatus instead of BatchStatus. Now everything is working fine.